# Order by most duplicate record first

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create table tbl_dup
(
    name varchar(100)
);

insert into tbl_dup values('Arsel Rous'),('Oram Rock'),('Oram Rock'),('Brown Twor'),
                          ('John Mak'),('Mak Dee'),('Smith Will'),('Mak Dee'),
                          ('John Mak'),('Oram Rock'),('John Mak'),('Oram Rock');
```

Query: I am looking for ordering the duplicate records should display at first level in the result set.

```
select * 
from
(
select name,row_number() over(partition by name order by name) rn 
from tbl_dup
) a
order by name,rn;
```

Getting:

```
name        rn
--------------
Arsel Rous  1
Brown Twor  1
John Mak    1
John Mak    2
John Mak    3
Mak Dee     1
Mak Dee     2
Oram Rock   1
Oram Rock   2
Oram Rock   3
Oram Rock   4
Smith Will  1
```

Expected Result:

```
name        rn
---------------
Oram Rock   1
Oram Rock   2
Oram Rock   3
Oram Rock   4
John Mak    1
John Mak    2
John Mak    3
Mak Dee     1
Mak Dee     2
Arsel Rous  1
Brown Twor  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `COUNT` as an analytic function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by name ORDER BY name) rn
FROM tbl_dup
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) DESC, rn;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You need to first order by the number of occurrence `desc` and row number by `asc`.

```
select name,rn 
from
(
    select name,row_number() over(partition by name order by name) rn ,
    count(*) over(partition by name) ct
    from tbl_dup
) a
order by ct desc, rn asc
```

Comment: You don't need `ORDER BY` in `COUNT`.